# How to check whether 2 regexp are the same accounting syntax differences?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm refactoring a rather large RegExp into a function that returns a RegExp. As a backward-compatibility test, I compared the `.source` of the returned RegExp with the `.source` of the old RegExp:

```
getRegExp(/* in the case requiring backward compatibility there's no arguments */)
    .source == oldRegExp.source
```

However, I've noticed that the old RegExp contains various excessive backslashes like `[\.\w]` instead of `[.\w]`. I'd like to refactor such bits, but there's a number of them and it would be nice to have a similar check (backward compability is not broken). The problem is, `/[\.\w]/.source != /[.\w]/.source`. And identifying which backslashes may be removed automatically is not trivial (`\.` and `.` are not the same outside `[...]` and may be in some other cases).

Are you aware of somewhat simple ways to do so? It seems this can only be done by actual parsing of the `.source` (compare the example above with `/\[\.\w]\/` and `/\[.\w]\/`), but may be I'm missing some trick of utilizing browser's built-in properties/methods. The point is, `'\"' == '"'` is true, so strings defined with these different syntaxes are stored as "normalized" values (`"`), I wonder if such "normalized" pattern is available for a RegExp.

Comment: @ggorlen could you clarify how `[.\w]` is different from `[\.\w]`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976308/3995261 (https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html). Yes, the backslash is excessive

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't realize that. Here's [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489095/how-to-determine-if-a-regex-is-orthogonal-to-another-regex) that has useful resources and is probably a better dupe than the above link. As Chris mentions below, I think proving two regexes are equivalent probably reduces to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: @ggorlen well, not exactly. Consider `'\"' == '"'` is true: these are the same string values (`"`) defined with different syntax. I wonder if RegExp have a similar "normalized" representation which is available natively and could be compared (pity that `.source` is not).

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, comparing two regular expressions to see if they're the same is exactly the same as comparing any other two pieces of code - ie, hard.

The only real way I know of to do this is to create a suite of tests, each one targeting a specific aspect of the regular expression and verifying that it works properly. This is not an easy process-regular expressions are subtle and complex with a lot of potential for unrealized side effects. I recently had to fix some defects in a regex based address parser and it took about a thousand unit tests before I was satisfied with my coverage... but then as soon as I started to change the regex ***MY TESTS CAUGHT STUFF CONSTANTLY!!***

Unit testing sucks and it's just tiring and not fun, but for almost any piece of logic it has real value, and when using powerful tools like regex, I would say it's absolutely crucial.

Comment: yeah, I'm thinking about tests too (actually, I already have a number of them), it's just, like you mentioned, lack of confidence because of "unknown" coverage